# One "not-so-normalised' table vs Two normalised tables - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, architecture, psql

I am stuck with a design decision. It seems that the answer on my question always depends on the specific situation. Here is my situation:

In my relational database I have a category and sub_category tables already. You can make posts and comments that are either linked to the category or sub_category.

Is it wise to have one posts and one comments table in my database and include a 'type' field in the comment and post tables to distinguish if the post/comment belongs to a category or a sub_category.

Or is it better to split the post and comment tables up into a category_post/category_comment and sub_category_post/sub_category_comment tables?

I am looking for the solution that will optimise speed. I am also looking to follow an architecture pattern that is scalable due to the fact that posts and comments can grow in size quite quickly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one, definitely:  one posts table and one comments table.  I would give each of them a category_id field and a subcategory_id field, so each can link to a category and/or subcategory.  I don't think you need the type field.

I'd be tempted to simplify it further and not even have a seperate table for subcategories:  instead, make category be a "tree" type model, ie have a category_id field in categories, so categories can be nested.  Then you can have a) more than one level of nesting of categories, which is likely to be a requirement at some point and b) have a situation where there's no logical difference between a category and subcategory, other than that defined in the data (ie how they have been nested), which makes your app simpler (and simple = good).

So:

```
#fields - category_id
Post
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :category

#fields - post_id, category_id
Comment
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :category  

#fields - parent_id
Category
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => :parent_id
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => :parent_id
```

Comment: Thanks you Max. Wow wish I spoke to you two months ago before making category and sub_category tables separately. Will keep it in mind in future. For now I will use your first set of advice.

Comment: A useful heuristic that i try to use when designing schema is "Imagine my boss comes along in 12 months time and adds some more requirements: how can i keep things simple now to allow flexibility later?"

Comment: I am attempting to implement the parent-child model. Some of the problems I am running into at the moment is that Category and Sub-category have different fields for example Category has name, suburb and city fields while sub-category only has a name field. I am not so concerned about my table not being normalised. What I am concerned about is losing validation that I usually enforce on category but now I maybe need to turn off my validation to allow sub-categories to be created in the same table. Any way around this?

Comment: You should put this in a new question.